# Django and staticfiles

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles, static-files

I have a problem with Django static files.

Let's assume, that the Django is configured to be server at **[www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app)**.

When my configuration is:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/hostxxx/domains/webpage.com/DjangoApp/static"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/hostxxx/domains/webpage.com/DjangoApp/media"
```

Then Django looks for:
`https://example.com/static/styles/style.css`

and it doesn't exist:

`GET https://example.com/static/styles/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

but the file exists here:

`https://example.com/app/static/styles/style.css`

But when I change the static url:

```
STATIC_URL = "/app/static/"
```

Then it looks for a good url:
`https://example.com/app/static/styles/style.css`
but now the staticfile is available here:
`https://example.com/app/app/static/styles/style.css`

Update:

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.lists, name="lists"), # MAIN VIEW
]
```

but tried also this as urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.lists, name="lists"),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>AAA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}">  # HERE
...
```

The hosting use passenger_wsgi.py, which is:

```
import imp
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source("wsgi", "app/wsgi.py")
application = wsgi.application
```

`django-admin --version`: `5.0`

`python --version`: `Python 3.10.13`

The solution offered on every other topic:
`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/app"`
does not work. Django template is still searching for: `https://example.com/static/styles/style.css` and not for: `https://example.com/app/static/styles/style.css`.

I've read a lot of answers and tried many times, nothing help.

It works fine, when I set the Django project without the app prefix: **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**, but I have other application served there, I need to add the prefix.

I don't understand, why it cannot generate a valid link for css:
[image]
The `app/` part is still missing.

How should I properly configure Django staticfiles to serve and search for this css?
https://example.com/app/static/styles/style.css

Comment: Have you tried with `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` ?

Comment: Show urls.py with static url patterns and the template where you refer to mentioned static file.

Comment: @Zatigem yes, tried that also, situation is the same - ```https://example.com/app/static/styles/style.css``` 
exists, but Django looks for 
```https://example.com/static/styles/style.css```

Comment: @IvanStarostin I updated the question, urls.py and template looks okay for me, but please say what do you think.

Comment: Are we speaking about local development and `runserver` or the website is already deployed at some hosting and is served by nginx or whatever?

Comment: @IvanStarostin it is already hosted on the server. The server takes passenger_wsgi.py as an "application starting file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production the webserver serves your static files. Therefore it is important to move/copy the files to a location where the server then directs to. That you can do with the comfy command `python manage.py collectstatic`. This you probably knew and have already done.

Depending on the folder structure the files end up with a different structure within created folder for the staticfiles.
Given the following structure:

```
myproject/
 - myapp1/
   - static/
     - myapp1/
       - css/
         - styles.css
```

Remember to give it namespacing, meaning within the static directory of myapp1 you create another directory called the same as the app (myapp1). When you run `collectstatic` now the staticfiles end up at `<STATIC_ROOT>/myapp1/css/styles.css` and you would address them in your template with `href="{% static 'myapp1/css/style.css' %}"`. This allows you to separate styles inbetween your apps. Please mention that you have to add the appname, here (myapp1) to the static path.

Ok so far so good. Now the next step is to configure your webserver in a way that it serves the staticfiles correctly. Issued url that has to be satisfied is `www.yourdomain.com/static/myapp1/css/styles.css`. You have to configure your webserver that it leads every request to `www.yourdomain.com/static/` to your staticfolder, which is located at `<STATIC_ROOT>`.

I am kind of sure your projects directory structure is misleading the collectstatic command. Another reason might be the false config of your webserver. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Tarquinius.
I had everything set up as you suggested and Django was still looking for the wrong address.
However, you gave me an idea that I can configure the hosting to serve staticfiles from a main location instead of the /app location.
Right now I have static files mixed with WordPress and Django (the WordPress app was on the server before and I wanted to add the Django app), but at least it works.